# Search string for first word that has an exclamation-mark

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
$string = 'Hello k-on! Lorem Ipsum! Lorem.';
```

I want to *get* the first word that is followed by an exclamation-mark. So in the example above, it should be:

```
$word = 'k-on';
```

I'm lost as to what's the appropriate approach to take. Maybe a regex solution?

Comment: Please share what you've tried.

Comment: do you require output as `k-on` and `Ipsum`? as these both have exclamations.

Comment: @ameenulla0007 I only want to target the *first* word with an exclamation mark.

Comment: Maybe `([a-zA-Z-]+?)!` with `preg_match`?.. or `(\S+?)!`

Comment: I bet it is `'/\b[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*!/i'` (ASCII only) or `'/\b\p{L}+(?:-\p{L}+)*!/u'` (to support Unicode). To be used with `preg_match`, of course.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Interesting. Can you please post an answer with the unicode preg_match() approach? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to only support ASCII letter words, you can use

```
/\b[a-z]+(?:-[a-z]+)*!/i
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hO1mU4/1)

If you plan to support Unicode, use `\p{L}`:

```
/\b\p{L}+(?:-\p{L}+)*!/u
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hO1mU4/2)

Here is the pattern explanation:

- `\b` - a word boundary (the previous character must be a non-word one or the beginning of the string)
- `\p{L}+` - 1 or more Unicode characters (or ASCII if `[a-zA-Z]` is used)
- `(?:-\p{L}+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `-`  - a literal hyphen
  - `\p{L}+` - 1 or more Unicode characters (or ASCII if `[a-zA-Z]` is used)
- `!` - a literal `!` symbol

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/KNDw1g):

```
$re = '/\b\p{L}+(?:-\p{L}+)*!/u'; 
$str = "Hello k-ąn! Lorem Ipsum! Lorem.";
preg_match($re, $str, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Comment: For completion, can you please add preg_match() example given that this is tagged with php. I will accept this as correct in a minute when it's possible.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a PHP demo. (I have had a "WORKIN ON UR PROBLEMZ SO page when accessing questions, so I could not update the answer earlier).

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do what you're looking for. Basically split the string into words, look for the first word that ends in '!', do whatever then break out of the loop:

```
$string = 'Hello k-on! Lorem Ipsum! Lorem.';
arry = explode(" ", $string);
foreach ($arry as $word) {
   if (substr($word,-1) == "!") {
      do something ...
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'Hello k-on! Lorem Ipsum! Lorem.';
preg_match('/[A-Za-z0-9-]+!/', $string, $match);
$yourWord   = str_replace("!", "", $match[0]); //prints k-on
```

obviously, the Solution for the requirement is `RegExp`, here i used a simple expression which allows AlphaNumeric String, exceptionally allowing hyphen(-) as well. use of `preg_match` matches the pattern into the string and returns the first matching keyword, which in your case is `k-on!` and used `str_replace` in order to take out the exclamation from the returned string.

know more about `preg_match` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php